# Drupal 7 Ubercart - taxes conditions related to delivering/billing address. How to configure?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, ubercart

I tried to set conditions into tax, but when open the **conditions** section and making condition it doesn't have finished result

1. Taxes list
   [image]
2. Opened conditions section of the tax
   [image]
3. Choosing of condition, and i have note here: I don't see needed conditions, only country conditions
   [image]
4. Then I tried to choose the details of condition 
   [image]

And when i try to add **order:uc-addresses-delivery-address:**
I see the **user:** option and then I have an eternal loop again and again between *uc-addresses-default-shipping-address* and *user*

5. Any trying to save this gives the error: Data selector order:uc-addresses-delivery-address:user:uc-addresses-default-shipping-address:user:uc-addresses-default-shipping-address:user:uc-addresses-default-shipping-address: for parameter order is invalid.

What i need to do for the taxes address(state/province) condition?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is here:

1) Add the condition, choose **Data comparizon**
[image]

2) Type **order:billing-address:zone** or choose these items in list and **Continue** creation
[image]

3) Choose needed Region/State/Province
[image]

4) Then save it. **Done!**